# How to export a unique ID field of a geopackage

Tags: shapefile, ogr, geopackage, unique-id

When I am converting my geopackage file in shapefile, the unique ID field is not exported. I could duplicate it before exportation, but I wanted to know if it could be done in one step, in order not to modify my geopackage. I am using ogr2ogr to make the conversion.

Comment: If you run `ogrinfo your_geopackage.gpkg -al -so`, what is the name of the FID column, and is that the unique ID field that you want to save into shapefile?

Comment: Indeed, the FID column is the attribute field NewID (FID Column = NewID) that I would like to save in the shapefile, in addition to the other attribute fields.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -dialect SQLite -sql "select NewID as source_id,* from your_layer" exported_layer.shp your_geopackage.gpkg
```

It may not be necessary to rename NewID, or it may work if you rename it with an original name `select NewID as NewID...`. I had a test with GeoPackage using field "fid" as FID and then I had to rename it.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it is working fine! I used "select NewID as NewID". Best regards, Philippe

Comment: @PhilippeMalcorps, if this answer solved your question, please accept it (and probably upvote it as well). See https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.